# IntelliJ IDEA - Find in path is locked in another window monitor

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-idea-2018

There is a problem in my IntelliJ IDEA. When I open Find in Path it is shown in a modal window in the second monitor instead in a window inside the main window like it did before. There is no way to move that window to main monitor. I don't remember if I change some configuration which caused this problem, but I'm pretty sure not.

I tried to restore default window configuration in `Window/Restore Default Layout`. But it didn't help. I'd like to restore the previous behavior without reset all configurations (by delete the config folder), since there is a lot configuration I've to do in IntelliJ IDEA  before I can get to work.

Below is an image of both monitor windows.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.4 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-181.5087.20, built on May 16, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b39 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.13.0-39-generic
```

Comment: Can you just drag and move it to the main display? Does it persist the position after moving?

Comment: I cannot move it neither resize.

Comment: Seems like the title bar doesn't respond to clicks.

Comment: Actually, sometimes I can move it but only in the same monitor until the screen limit and sometimes it doesn't respond to clicks. The behavior is strange and unusual.

Comment: Can you try https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/? I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Same problem with newer versions. Is there a way to reset only this configuration?

Comment: Close IDE, navigate to the [config directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519), `options` subdirectory, delete `dimensions.xml` file.

Comment: Ther is now a ticket for this issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-192093

Answer (score 4):

After you click on the window header keep moving the mouse pointer to the other monitor until the find window jumps to the other monitor.  In some cases you have to move the mouse quite a bit.

Looks like the window can not be in two monitors at the same time.

I have Android Studio 3.6.1

Comment: This worked for me. Another related hint is for those that have monitors set up vertically - one above another - I was not able to move through the top of the screen, as I do with any other app, but instead I had to move it far-left or far-right then it appears on the other screen.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. It was quite far up the page before it "bumped" up too.  (I'm working on a Macbook Pro M3)

Answer (score 4):

I realize this post is quite old, but I just had the same problem. I could solve it by removing the state of the popup in the `workspace.xml`. You do not have to delete all you configurations etc for the project.
Just go to `workspace.xml` -> `<component name="WindowStateProjectService">` and then find the problematic popup and delete its state. For me this solved the problem, it's possible though that you actually have to set the x and y coordinates to have the popup show up at the right place (I didn't need to fwiw).

Comment: Thank you for that comment. Deleting specific configurations in `~/.config/phpstorm` folder was not enough. You need to find specific configuration in your project `.idea` folder and delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Besides changing configuration file, alternative for me solution (Linux, Ubuntu) is:

- **closing "Find in path" window** with ESC,
- opening it again **Ctrl+Shift+F**.
- Only on initial open one will get handle to **resize window's width to smaller width** then screen if one goes far left or right to the edge of "Find in path" dialog.
- When resized to smaller width then screen width, one will be able to
  **move this dialog to another screen** (it seems this is happening due
  window edge snapping)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS I found that the best solution is to change your main display by draggin the menu bar to where you want your "Find in files"-popup.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with IntelliJ 2020.3.3: The "Find in Path" Window always appeared on the laptop screen instead of the main screen. It was full-width (but not full-height), and I was able to move and resize it vertically, but not horizontally - and thus not onto the screen to the right.

**But I was able to drag the window by holding the "Alt"-key while dragging**. It was the again-fullwidth on the other, correct screen, but still not resizable in width. After closing and opening again it was still on the correct screen, and not full-width anymore.